# PostgreSQL full text search not finding some words it should find

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, full-text-search

If I do a:

```
select to_tsvector('Angel of Mercy')
```

I get a `'angel':1 'mercy':3 'of':2` as a result of this query. So when I do a:

```
select to_tsvector('Angel of Mercy') @@ to_tsquery('Mercy')
```

I get a `true` as a result. Indeed, "mercy" is in the vector.

`of` is a stop word, but I guess it is present because I didn't inform the language, english in that case. When I do it:

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'Angel of Mercy')
```

I get a `'angel':1 'merci':3`. `of` is not present anymore, and this is expected behavior. "Mercy" gets transformed into `merci` lexeme, and this is understandable. But when I do a:

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'Angel of Mercy') @@ to_tsquery('Mercy')
```

I get `[]` as result (which I think it should be `false` as I read in the docs, but whatever). So, searching "Mercy" in a table that have an entry like "Angel of Mercy" did not retrieve any results.

Is this the desired behavior? What am I missing here? How can I retrieve "Angel of Mercy" querying by "mercy", "merciful", "mercilessly" and other similar words?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config setting must agree between the vector and the query processing.  we don't know what your default_text_search_config is set to, but clearly it is not english.

```
select to_tsvector('english', 'Angel of Mercy') @@ to_tsquery('english','Mercy')
```

Note the 'Mercilessly' does not get stemmed "correctly" even in english setting.

Comment: In every tutorial I found I didn't see anyone refering to configuration in to_tsquery. I think this happens because the authors may not realize that their audience could not be from english native countries. You nailed it clearly with your answer.

Comment: Don't read tutorials, read the fine PostgreSQL manual.